# Robot.mouseWheel doesn't work using Java

Tags: java

All operations are:
1, click the windows logo to open the "All Program"
2, click "All Program"
3, move mouse up to the program list
4, wheeling down

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(35,1062);    //click windows logo
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.delay(1000);
System.out.println("open windows");

robot.mouseMove(70,947);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
System.out.println("open all program");
robot.delay(1000);

robot.mouseMove(88,510);
System.out.println("move to chrome");
robot.delay(1000);

for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++){
    robot.mouseWheel(1);
    robot.delay(1000);
}
```

but the mouseWheel doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 20 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and `robot.mouseWheel` works correctly.
Its problem may be of not being active window in your situation.

But I recommend use following code to open chrome and search in it:

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    //-- open start menu
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.delay(1000);

    //-- type ch to find chrome
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.delay(1000);

    //-- press Enter to Open it
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.delay(1000);

    //-- type hi to search
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
    robot.delay(1000);

    //-- press Enter to search it
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

To scroll down on programs in windows 10 I wrote the following code and it works Correctly on my computer with 1920x1080 resolution (but using it is not recommended because the manner may differ in various condition):

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    //-- open start menu
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.delay(1000);

    //-- to move on programs
    robot.mouseMove(250,700);

    //-- scroll down
    for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        robot.mouseWheel(1);
        robot.delay(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  The Robot.mouseWheel works fine on the Chrome browser interface, but not on the "All Program". My main propose is testing mouse wheel, but thanks all the same.